# When should one use multiple DispatcherServlets in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, dispatch

Spring MVC allows for multiple `DispatcherServlet`s. However, I can't find single case when using multiple `DispatcherServlet`s is more useful than single instance. Could you provide a scenario in which multiple `DispatcherServlet`s have advantage over single instance?

Comment: Strictly seperating user and admin functionality. Or one for plain Spring MVC and another for Spring Web Flow. If there are major configuration differences for some controllers. (We actually used the Spring MVC and Spring Web Flow seperation so that we could add this without affecting the already exising configs). Nowadays with servlet 3.0 you could develop seperate parts of your application seperatly and have all of them contribute there own `DispatcherServlet` and mappings (although you could also achieve this with some configuration conventions).